# QuickWatch-like control for .NET WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Visual Studio QuickWatch window has a hierarchical property grid control. Is a control like that available somewhere?

The default property grid control doesn't seem to work for me as it requires the objects to have an ExpandableConverter attribute to work the way I want. Although, if any of you know a way to turn the property grid into a QuickWatch-like control it would also be accepted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is very spread type of control. Each Library-of-Controls company created at least one.

http://images.google.com.ua/images?q=tree%20like%20grid

Comment: Thanks for your response but I mean a particular kind of tree grid that receives an object instance and lists it's properties hierarchically

Comment: I have bad news. You really have to spend several minutes to implement that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two samples:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PropertyGridExWinForms.aspx
<strike>http://www.howtocode.net/software-development/c/propertygrid-utilities</strike>

Comment: The second link has since broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, its something you would have to create your self.

looks like it wouldn't be to difficult, I think its DataGridView where the first column is a custom cell that when clicked does a hit test to see if its hit a node glyph.

But i could be wrong.